# PHP cannot show tables from MySqli Query

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to figure out why I can connect to a database, but cannot access the data in it.

Here's my configuration:

```
//config.php
<?php
define("HOST", "MYSERVERNAMEISHERE");
define("DATABASE", "users");
?>
```

My user logs in, and their information is passed to be checked:

```
//login.php
<?php
if ($_POST) {
    if ($_POST["user"] && $_POST["password"]) {
        include_once "config.php";
        define("USER", $_POST["user"]);
        define("PASSWORD", $_POST["password"]);
        $link = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
        if ($link) {
            $link->close();
            if ($_SESSION) {
                session_destroy();
            }
            session_start();
            $_SESSION["user"] = $_POST["user"];
            $_SESSION["password"] = $_POST["password"];
        }
    }
}
if ($_SESSION) {
    header('Location: profile.php');
}
else {
    header('Location: login.html');
}
?>
```

When they pass, they get to see their profile page.

```
//profile.php
<?php
session_start();
if (!$_SESSION["user"] || !$_SESSION["password"]) {
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: login.html");
}
else {
    include_once "config.php";
}
$link = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE) or die("Unable to connect to database");
$result = $link->query("SHOW TABLES") or die("Unable to show tables");
...
ADDITIONAL PHP AND HTML CODE AFTER THIS POINT
```

The problem is that the process dies when I try to query the mysqli link. (I get `Unable to show tables`) Right now, the `SHOW TABLES` is just filler for debugging; I will actually have useful mysqli queries when I figure out the issue.

Please help me determine where my bug is. If you find a typo or a reference link for me, sorry for wasting your time. I've been researching and debugging for hours now.

Thanks very much in advance.

PS: If you have some good advice for changes I should make, I appreciate those too. It's my first time making a user login.

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure that you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: I do not see where you're querying the database. You appear to be allowing every user access to your database....which is not likely.

Comment: instead of using that measly `unable to show tables` message, use `->error` property instead

Comment: @JayBlanchard I guess I was right about a comment I deleted in regards to USER and PASSWORD not being defined, *hah*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Notice: Undefined variable and Notice: Undefined index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: You need to put `exit()` after you redirect to `login.html`. Otherwise, it will still try to do the `SHOW TABLES` query.

Comment: @JayBlanchard and RodrigoDuterte Thank you for the advice. Like I said, I am a total noob, and very much appreciate your insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query in profile.php is failing because `USER` and `PASSWORD` are not defined. When the person logs in, they are defined in login.php. When redirected to profile.php, `USER` AND `PASSWORD` do not have values since they are not in config.php.

In profile.php, change

```
$link = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE) or die("Unable to connect to database");
```

to

```
$link = new mysqli(HOST, $_SESSION["user"], $_SESSION["password"], DATABASE) or die("Unable to connect to database");
```

Comment: I just found it myself. I marked as correct. Would upvote if I could. I also found that I was not properly vetting the login information. Thanks for the quick response.